# Stopping SASS Parent Selector (with pseudo classes) from cascading into childs within

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a SASS parent selector, it works great! However the HTML markup has the pseudo-classes all propagated/cascaded into the childs within, here's my CSS:

```
.news-image-container {
  .accent-styling & {
    :after {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      height: 8px;
      background-color: var(--news-accent-border-color);
      top: -8px;
    }
    :before {
      content: '';
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid var(--news-accent-border-color);
      bottom: -10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the markup, notice all the **:before**'s and **:after**'s... how do I stop all the other ones from appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the ampersand beside the pseudo classes like this: `&:before` and `&:after`. Check this article as well: [The Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)